# Where can I break down mutagens?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In Witcher 3 you need several "generic" mutagens in order to craft a greater mutagen, and I think I saw somewhere that you can dismantle them. For example, take a griffin mutagen and get a generic lesser green one. Or was I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot break down Mutagens - you have to find them on monsters, and craft them through Lesser -> Regular -> Greater.

Comment: With the Blood and Wine DLC, this answer is no longer correct

Answer (score 3):

There is only one place you can do this At the table at the hidden laboratory in the cave under the estate at corvo bianco

Answer (score 0):

You can break down mutagens in [the Ghost Mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/witcher3/mods/992).

Answer (score -1):

You can break down mutagens by dismantling them at a blacksmith.

Comment: I just checked, and you can't dismantle mutagens, they don't appear in the list of items that can be dismantled.

Comment: @Bob: You might mean crafting materials, like Monster Hide?